# What is the most elegant way to update a child collection when using nhibernate (without creating unnecessary adds and deletes)?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, nhibernate

I have an domain object called Project which maps to a table in my SQL server database. It has a property that is a List called Dependencies.

```
   public class Project
   {
         public int Id;
         public List<ProjectDependency> Dependencies;   
   }

   public class ProjectDependency
   {
          public Project Project;
          public Project Dependency;
   }
```

and and I trying to figure out the most efficient way to update the list of dependencies given a new list of dependencyIds.

So here is a naive implementation:

```
 public void UpdateDependencies(Project p, List<int> newDependencyIds)
 {
       p.Dependencies.Clear();
       foreach (var dependencyId in newDependencyIds)
       {
             Project d = GetDependency(dependencyId)
             p.Dependencies.Add(new ProjectDependency{Project = p, Dependency = d});
       }
 }
```

but the issue here is that even if nothing changes, I am clearing out all items and doing inserts on the same items that were there before.

I am looking for an elegant way to determine the diff (whats been added, whats been removed) and just make those changes so if a dependency was there before and after then it doesn't get touched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public void UpdateDependencies(Project p, List<int> newDependencyIds)
    {
        p.Dependencies.RemoveAll(d => !newDependencyIds.Contains(d.Dependency.Id));
        var toAdd = newDependencyIds.Select(d => p.Dependencies.Any(pd => pd.Dependency.Id != d)).ToList();
        toAdd.ForEach(dependencyId => p.Dependencies.Add(new ProjectDependency{Project = p, Dependency = GetDependency(dependencyId)}));
    }
```

Comment: On the last line in your response, i am getting and error saying can't add lambda expression.  I think there is something wrong with the logic

Comment: I think there is a Typo the dependencyId => should be immediately after the ForEach(

Answer (score 2):

I am really confused about your `Model` classes. You are creating a class `Project`.

```
public class Project
{
     public int Id;
     ...  
}
```

which itself is referred in another class -

```
public class ProjectDependency
{
    public Project Project;
    public Project Dependency;
}
```

and again you are referring that referrer class inside the referred class? -

```
public class Project
{
     public int Id;
     public List<ProjectDependency> Dependencies;   //that is a cycle and it is very bad architecture
}
```

Why on earth would you want to do that? Isn't that too much cycles in there?

**SOLUTION:** (EDITED)

I would suggest a simpler model like this -

```
public class Project
{
     public int Id;
     public List<ProjectDependency> Dependencies; 
}

public class ProjectDependency
{
     //..... other property
     public Project DependentProject; 
}
```

That is it. That is my class. Why? Because `NHbernate` will automatically create the required foreign key. And since you are using ORM, I don't think it would matter how much table and what columns the ORM creates to supports you, it is the ORM's headache not users. But still if you want you can always override it with a `ManyToMany` reference, so that a separate table is used.

Now, after the class definition is fixed I would go with something like this to update my dependencies -

```
public class Project
{
     public int Id;
     public List<ProjectDependency> Dependencies; 

     public List<ProjectDependency> AddDepedency(List<ProjectDependency> dependencies){
          dependencies.ForEach(d => {
               if (Dependencies.All(x=> x.Id != d.Id)){
                    Dependencies.Add(d);
               }
          });
          return Dependencies;
     }

     public List<ProjectDependency> RemoveDepedency(List<ProjectDependency> dependencies){
          dependencies.ForEach(d => {
               if (Dependencies.Any(x=> x.Id == d.Id)){
                    Dependencies.Remove(d);
               }
          });
          return Dependencies;
     }

     public List<ProjectDependency> UpdateDependency(List<ProjectDependency> dependencies){
          dependencies.ForEach(d => {
               if (Dependencies.All(x=> x.Id != d.Id)){
                    Dependencies.Add(d);
               }
          });
          Dependencies.RemoveAll(d => depdencies.All(x => x.Id != d.Id));
          return Depdendencies;
     }
}
```

Things to note -

1. Instead of sending `List<int>` i am sending `List<ProjectDependency>`, this is because `Model` should not know about services to fetch from database in the system and thus they will only worry about classes.
2. No matter what in the current list, `UpdateDependency` will replace it with the list provided. So sooner or later the items are going to be fetched from db. So its better if they are prefethed and passed as `ProjectDependency` object. This will keep the architecture clean.
3. I added two extra method, Add and Remove, this is the actual way that I would have done it. But since you are using `UpdateDependency` I added that one too.
4. Also note that I am returning the list in each function, this will help in nesting the methods when used with other services and classes. It helps you reduce one line of code each time you use those methods that needs a chaining.

Last, but not the least, I haven't tested the code. So you might find some spelling or syntax error. If you like the code, then do change or fix the errors if any and use it.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response.  In terms of your first point, i have other fields in the bridge table (the ProjectDependency table) but i didn't include them to simplify the question and not distract from the main point.  Apologies if this caused you to spend effort focusing on that point.  Please let me know how your answer changes given this point.

Comment: Yes, it  makes me change the answer. but still I usually prefer avoiding cycles, I usually use one way assignment. Because unless you are not using a good architecture, you would not need to call parent in any case, that is why it's a child entity, not the parent one.

Answer (score 2):

Please take this as a base idea.

In your case it will be better to work with `HashSet<>` for actual collection and `ICollection<T>` for declaration. When retrieving from database NHibernate will use `ISet<>` for version <= 3.3 and HashSet for the >= 4.0 (currently in alpha).

Then in your `ProjectDependency` you should implement the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` override to correct identify if the same item is already present in the set.

With this, the `Contains` and all `Linq` operations should be able to detect duplicates.

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        this.Dependencies = new HashSet<ProjectDependency>();
    }
}

public class ProjectDependency
{
    public Project Project;
    public Project Dependency;

    // This is a simplified version and don't check for nulls in internal members
    // or transient objects
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Project.Id + this.Dependency.Id;
    }

    // This is a simplified version and don't check for nulls in internal members
    // or transient objects
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var dep = obj as ProjectDependency;
        if (dep == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.Project.Id == dep.Project.Id && this.Dependency.Id == dep.Dependency.Id;
    }
}
```

Now, you update method can be simplified to:

```
public void UpdateDependencies(Project p, List<int> newDependencyIds)
{
    var newDependencies = newDependencyIds.Select(d => new ProjectDependency{ Project = p, Dependency = GetDependency(d) });

    var addDependencies = newDependencies.Except(p.Dependencies);
    var delDependencies = p.Dependencies.Except(newDependencies);

    foreach (var dependency in addDependencies)
    {
        p.Dependencies.Add(dependency);
    }

    foreach (var dependency in delDependencies)
    {
        p.Dependencies.Remove(dependency);
    }
}
```

Now it will only update the modified items.

**UPDATE:** Added suggestions from @doan-van-tuan to this answer.

**UPDATE 2:** Please consider the following if your `ProjectDependency` class doesn't have any other properties and are used only as a many-to-many class.

In this case, you can remove the `ProjectDependency` class, as below:

```
public class Project
{
    // This attribute is used to ensure GetHashCode always return the same value
    private int? hashCode;

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Dependencies { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        this.Dependencies = new HashSet<Project>();
    }

    // This is a simplified but correct implementation of GetHashCode
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (this.hashCode.HasValue)
        {
            return this.hashCode.Value;
        }

        if (this.Id == 0)
        {
            return (this.hashCode = base.GetHashCode()).Value;
        }

        return (this.hashCode = typeof(Project).GetHashCode() * this.Id * 251).Value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var p = obj as Project;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(p, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return p.Id == this.Id;
    }
}

public class ProjectMapping : ClassMapping<Project>
{
    public ProjectMapping()
    {
        this.Table("Project");

        this.Id(x => x.Id, mapper => mapper.Generator(Generators.Assigned));
        this.Set(x => x.Dependencies,
            mapper =>
            {
                mapper.Table("ProjectDependency");
                mapper.Key(m => m.Column("ProjectId"));
            },
            mapper =>
            {
                mapper.ManyToMany(m => m.Column("DependencyId"));
            });
    }
}
```

And your update method could be:

```
public void UpdateDependencies(Project p, IEnumerable<Project> newDependencies)
{
    var addDependencies = newDependencies.Except(p.Dependencies);
    var delDependencies = p.Dependencies.Except(newDependencies);

    foreach (var dependency in addDependencies)
    {
        p.Dependencies.Add(dependency);
    }

    foreach (var dependency in delDependencies)
    {
        p.Dependencies.Remove(dependency);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by >4.  It looks like 3.3.3 is the latest version: http://nhforge.org/

Comment: The [NHibernate 4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/4.0.0-Alpha2) stills in alpha and the major change is that it will replace the Iesi.Collections library in favor of the native .net collections.

Comment: I have used Set for these situation since NH2.2. This answer is correct , and should be awarded the bounty. Small addition to the answer: you do not have to use ISet. Use ICollection<T> and HashSet instead.

Comment: Edited the answer, replace ISet with ICollection.. For GetHashCode, if ProjectDependency has surrogate key, it'd be better to use that key for hash code, not the natural key pair (Project, Dependency)

Comment: @doan-van-tuan, someone undo your edit. I agree with you in two points. ICollection usage and use of virtual (my mistake here). About the surrogate key, I can't agree. As the same Project, Dependency pair can have different surrogate keys (of course you can use an unique index on database to avoid it). The hash in this case should reflect the contents of the object and for that it must be the key pair.

Comment: @SergioGarcia: Well, about surrogate key issue, from leora's code, it's clear that surrogate keys are not used, so this is not relevant to the question. This is just my style anyway, I prefer surrogate key. However, hash code should not be mutable, so you have to make sure object is immutable in order to use natural keys as hash code safely.

Comment: @doan-van-tuan: The GetHashCode implementation in my answer is denoted as a "simplified version". The correct GetHashCode implementation is complex and will just complicate the answer here and is out of topic for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a console app that will locate the unchanged, added and removed ProjectDependency Ids. It's easier to get the Ids because `List<int>` is passed to the UpdateDependencies method. Hope this helps.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var project = CreateProject();
        var newDependencyIds = new List<int>() {2, 3, 4, 13};
        UpdateDependencies(project, newDependencyIds);
    }

    private static Project CreateProject()
    {
        var project = new Project() {Id = 1};
        project.Dependencies = new List<ProjectDependency>();
        for (int projectId = 2; projectId < 10; projectId++)
        {
            var dependency = new ProjectDependency() {Project = project, Dependency = new Project() {Id = projectId}};
            project.Dependencies.Add(dependency);
        }
        return project;
    }

    private static void UpdateDependencies(Project p, List<int> newDependencyIds)
    {
        var oldDependencyIds = p.Dependencies.Select(d => d.Dependency.Id);
        var unchanged = oldDependencyIds.Intersect(newDependencyIds);
        var added = newDependencyIds.Except(oldDependencyIds);
        var removed = oldDependencyIds.Except(newDependencyIds);

        Console.WriteLine("Old ProjectDependency Ids: " + string.Join(", ", oldDependencyIds));
        Console.WriteLine("New ProjectDependency Ids: " + string.Join(", ", newDependencyIds));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Unchanged: " + string.Join(", ", unchanged));
        Console.WriteLine("Added: " + string.Join(", ", added));
        Console.WriteLine("Removed: " + string.Join(", ", removed));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Old ProjectDependency Ids: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
New ProjectDependency Ids: 2, 3, 4, 13

Unchanged: 2, 3, 4
Added: 13
Removed: 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you deriving that the Project has dependencies?  you only state that you have one table, so I'm assuming that there is not actually a table named ProjectDependency.

however, if there is such a table, it might be redundant. if there is only the Project table, then it is even easier.  bear with me:

if it was me and if I was able to modify the table, I would make Project have a self-referencing (recursive) foreign key.  such that that project table would then have a column named ParentProjectId of the same type as the primary key of the table project, that would then reference the primary key as a foreign key constraint.

something like this (this is for ms-sql server, but the concept should stand in other db's, if not let me know):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentProjectId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Project] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentProject_Project] FOREIGN KEY([ParentProjectId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Project] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ParentProject_Project]
GO
```

if that is possible, I would then model as follows:

```
public class Project
{
    private IList<Project> _dependencies;

    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Project> Dependencies
    {
        get { return _dependencies ?? (_dependencies = new List<Project>()); }
        set { _dependencies = value; }
    }

    public virtual Project ParentProject { get; set; }

    public virtual Project AddDependency(Project dependency)
    {
        dependency.ParentProject = this;
        Dependencies.Add(dependency);

        return this;
    }
}
```

then in the mapping I would map like so (pseudocode for now, will update):

```
public sealed class ProjectMap : ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name);

        References(x => x.ParentProject).Column("ParentProjectId").Cascade.All();

        HasMany(x => x.Dependencies).KeyColumn("ParentProjectId").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

this basically gives you the ability to have nested projects ad infinitum, using recursion.

now, based on your question, you are using nhibernate and your Project entity has a primary key of type int.  typically I would make that key an identity column as well, and my mapping above lets nhibernate know that the database will generate it.

just based on your post of asking ' most elegant way ' if it was me, based on your models, and assuming I had the ability/permissions to work with the database schema, this is how I would do it.

the way the AddDependency method works is that it handles connecting a dependency to the project, and when you actually do a Session.Save on the project entity, NHibernate will actually only insert those new projects.  and I would simply create or select new Projects and pass them in rather than trying to work with the id's, and just let the database handle that (because it is good at it)

I would probably not try and do a many to many but if that is what you actually need let me know and I will update my answer.  I'm just going off what you said that you have 'a table in my SQL server database'

hth

Comment: its a many to many relationship so a project shouldn't be contained to having a single "parent"